# How to sort by object's field which is inside object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have class RoomToday with some field. Inside this class there is a object of Room. I have no field name in RoomToday class.

```
class RoomToday {
    Room room;
    //other fields
}

class Room {
    String name;
    //
}
```

And i have repository RoomTodayrepository. Can i have method which sort by Room's name?

Something like that. This request must be in **JPA** repository:

```
List<RoomToday> findByIdInOrderByRoomNameAsc(Collection<UUID> id);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Comment: @NitinBisht I think he wants `JPA` to give him an already by a specific field sorted list

Comment: i don't think so. i want to sort it in jparepository on database request lvl if it is real

Comment: @CodeMatrix is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `Room` as `@Embeddable`,

```
class RoomToday {
    @Embedded
    Room room;
    //other fields
}
@Embeddable
class Room {
    String name;
    //
}
```

Then create a method in repository as below,

```
List<RoomToday> findByIdInOrderByRoomNameAsc(Collection<UUID> id);
```

Comment: so, how can I do that with relational object ?